# How to solve "requires python 2.x support" in linux vim,and it have python 2.6.6 in my system

Tags: python, linux, vim

```
[root@localhost bin]# python -V
Python 2.6.6
[root@localhost bin]# ./vim
UltiSnips requires py >= 2.6 or any py3
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with  Python 2.x support
```

i have try it in centos 6.4 ,and fedora 20. It's the same problem.
i am new coder ,i really do not know why it happen.

Answer (score 18):

In Ubuntu/Lubuntu 16.04, I have success with installing `vim-gnome-py2`

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome-py2
```

My `vim --version | grep python` after installing it:

```
$ vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
```

You may need to remove other packages such as `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk`, `vim-nox` ... to avoid conflicts.

Comment: As @neoben pointed out, running `sudo update-alternatives --set vim /usr/bin/vim.gnome-py2` works in place of removing other conflicting packages

Answer (score 17):

With Debian 8, installing `vim-nox` helped me.

```
apt-get install vim-nox
```

Answer (score 12):

Neovim? Anyone?

## Getting set up with neovim and ycm

### Installation

On arch, for example, `yaourt -S python-neovim`

Basically, you need python support.

### Setting up neovim

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nvim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
cp ~/.vimrc ./init.vim
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git
git clone 
nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim # edit nvim init file (using nvim, **of course** :)
```

### Using vundle to manage YCM:

Hopefully, you are still inside you `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` ... add these lines in order to add [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) and [You Complete Me (YCM)](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) plugins:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.config/nvim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin('~/.config/nvim/bundle')
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

**NOTE**
All of the above lines are **required** (with the exception of `Plugin 'vundleVim/Vundle.vim'` as that just tells vundle to manage itself for updates).

Now run these commands **inside nvim/vim** to (1) source the current file and (2) install all the plugins with vundle.

```
:so %
:PluginInstall
```

### Last step: compiling YCM

We need one last step for YCM. (Usually, you do not need to do this with Plugins as they will use vimL or something. However, YCM needs something a bit faster, so we need to do a little something more.)

```
cd ~/.config/nvim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/
python2 install.py
```

All done!
:)

## Getting set up in vim instead

### meh

If you insist, simply put all of vundle's things inside `~/.vim/bundle/` and then use

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin('~/.vim/bundle')
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe' " if on arch, I recommend installing vim-youcompleteme-git
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

inside your ~/.vimrc. **Note** the difference in the `set rtp+=` AND the `call vundle#begin` ... in vim  and nvim, they point to **different** directories.

Comment: Actually - just a small update - neovim is still under heavy development and sometimes you get a seg-fault. Vim's config directory is ~/.vim or ~/.config/vim and you can do the same thing in those. `:)`

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you didn't install vim with Python support.

You can check this by running `vim --version`.

If you see a `-python` string in the output, that means you didn't install it with Python support. `+python` means it's installed with Python support.

To resolve this, either find a package in your package manager that installs it with Python support (see other answers) or download the source code and compile it with Python support. (Run the `configure` script with `--enable-pythoninterp=yes`. If you want Python 3 support to be enabled, use `--enable-python3interp=yes`)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue installing *vim-gnome-py2* that has python2 interpreter support

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome-py2
```

and making it the default alternative using *update-alternatives*

```
sudo update-alternatives --set vim /usr/bin/vim.gnome-py2
```

**Installing vim-gnome-py2 could not be enough**

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04, I took these steps:

1. `cd ~/.vim/bundle`
2. `rm -rf YouCompleteMe/`
3. `vim +PluginInstall +qall`
4. `cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe`
5. `./install.sh --clang-completer`

No problems since then.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is explained in the message: your vim is not built with python support. The solution is also rather obvious: install vim with python support.

Use your package manager to install the biggest build available which I think is "vim-enhanced". Hopefully, your package manager will deal with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

That means python support was not included when compiling vim.

Check if your distribution has some package like `vim-with-full-features` (I heard that there is no in CentOS), or build it yourself. Happy vimming.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to install python-dev. He solved my problem.

`$ sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Answer (score 0):

## Don't ./configure both python (2) AND python3 interpreters:

On Ubuntu 16.04 when installing vim from source via:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr
```

The `enable-pythoninterp` and `enable-python3interp` when used together result in a `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn` as features which seems to cause trouble. You'll see this in the "features included (+)" if you run `vim --version`.

**Don't configure both.** i.e. Only use one python (or the other) and things will start to function correctly.

---

Looks like this was answered (with more info) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23656675/1442914

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, Python support was not working due to enabling both Python2 and Python3.

I solve the problem by only enabling Python3. When i enabling both Python2 and Python3, run "echo has(python) || has('python3')" in vim, but it output 0. After unenabling python, "echo has(python3)" output 1, "echo has(python)" output 0.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:
NB: I'm compiling vim with Python 2; Python 3 was giving me some issues for some weird reason.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vim vim-runtime vim-gnome vim-tiny vim-gui-common   

sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-dev luajit libluajit-5.1 python-dev ruby-dev libperl-dev libncurses5-dev libatk1.0-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev   

" Optional: so vim can be uninstalled again via dpkg -r vim  
sudo apt-get install checkinstall   

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/vim /usr/bin/vim  

cd ~  
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim   
cd vim  
git pull && git fetch  

" In case Vim was already installed  

cd src  
make distclean  
cd .. 

./configure \  
--enable-multibyte \  
--enable-perlinterp=dynamic \  
--enable-rubyinterp=dynamic \  
--with-ruby-command=/usr/local/bin/ruby \  
--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic \  
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu \    
--enable-luainterp \  
--with-luajit \  
--enable-cscope \  
--enable-gui=auto \  
--with-features=huge \  
--with-x \  
--enable-fontset \  
--enable-largefile \  
--disable-netbeans \  
--with-compiledby="yourname" \  
--enable-fail-if-missing  

make && sudo make install
```

````

Answer (score 0):

In my case the accepted answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/requires-vim-compiled-with-python-2-7-1-or-3-4-support) solved it. When executing the configure script you should omit the deprecated parameter `--with-python-config-dir=`.