# Vim compiled with Python support but can't see sys version

Tags: python, vim, fedora

I compiled the development version of Vim with both Python 2 and Python 3 support. The output of `vim --version` has `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn` in it. I ran the configure file with 
g
`./configure --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python3.3/config --with-x --with-features=huge`

However when I run `:python import sys; print(sys.version)` I get

```
E448: Could not load library function _PyArg_Parse_SizeT  
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

Why would this be? I found out because of YouCompleteMe stating that it requires Vim compiled with 2.x support.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible it was compiled for a different version of 2.x that what you're using? It's only a guess, but C extensions definately need to be compiled for the specific version.

Comment: I have [the same problem before in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349930/how-can-i-add-with-python-options-by-building-gvim-vim-from-source-code-in-wi), and the reason is the version of my python/python3 is **64bit**. After I installed **32bit python/python3**, everything's fine.

Comment: Why would it matter if it's 64 vs 32 bit?

Comment: Vim is 32 bit so it can't load your 64 bit python library. It's that simple.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. So I need the 32bit Python installation to use with Vim. Thanks!

Comment: Does **32bit** works?

Comment: Sorry just came back to this. I found it works if I only enable the normal Python interpreter, but when I enable the Python3 one it makes both have the /dyn and thus auto complete doesn't work

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar issue on my Debian box.  If you're using a Debian-based system, you will not be able to load both Python libraries simultaneously.  That's why when you set `--enable-python-interp` and `--enable-python3-interp` they always load with the /dyn suffix.

If your vim plugins don't need both versions, you should just pick one of the versions and stick with it.  The links below provide more info.

[Explained by Debian maintainer](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=10;att=0;bug=729924)

[Vim Python Support](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html#python3)

P.S. - In case you tried this on Windows as well, loading either Python version will work, so the /dyn isn't an issue there.

Comment: @chirinosky If I'm reading this (and the links) right, there isn't any fix for this, and we have to live with whichever Python is loaded first. Am I getting this right?

Comment: @batbrat Yes, you basically have to pick one or the other.

Comment: I'm going ahead and compiling against just one version of Python. Since Python 2 support is coming to an end, I've picked Python 3, although arguments can be made for the opposite. Thanks for your help.